# Probability of having rolled the unfair die given the result of a roll.

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Let's say I have a box with two dice. One of them is a regular die and the other has 3 on every face. Without looking, I randomly pick one of the dice, roll it, and see that I got a 3. I still don't know whether I rolled the fair or unfair die.

Does the fact that I rolled a 3 on my first roll change the likelihood that the die I rolled was the fair or unfair one, and if so, by how much?

Comment: Do you know about Bayes' rule? I think that might be helpful here. It's also helpful to think about the other extreme case. Suppose you rolled something other than a 3 - does this change the likelihood that the die you rolled is the fair one?

Comment: Yes, I've learned Bayes' rule, but I'm confused about how to use it because I can't just check the probability of choosing one of the dice given that I rolled six (since the probability of rolling six is itself dependent on which dice I chose). Maybe I don't correctly understand how to apply Bayes' rule?

Comment: What would you think if both dice have 1000000 faces?

Comment: Well I guess I would think that it's more likely that I chose the unfair die. I still don't understand what I can to do to calculate the probability though.

Comment: You can apply your definitions and Bayes' Theorem.  Let $A$ be the event that you picked the unfair die.  Let $B$ be the event that you rolled a $3$.  You should be able to tell *immediately* what $Pr(B\mid A), Pr(B\mid A^c), Pr(A),$ and $Pr(A^c)$ are from the problem statement.  You are asked to find $Pr(A\mid B)$.  Recall that $Pr(A\mid B) = \dfrac{Pr(A\cap B)}{Pr(B)} = \dfrac{Pr(B\mid A)Pr(A)}{Pr(B)}$.  The only slightly challenging missing piece of information being to calculate $Pr(B)$ which can be found with all of the given information.

Comment: You have three events $F=$ the fair die was chosen, $U$=the unfair die was chosen, $X=3$ three was rolled.  You want to compute $\Pr(F|X=3)$.  Can you apply Bayes' rule now?

Comment: How can I calculate just the probability of rolling a three if it changes depending on which die I chose. If I chose the unfair die, then the probability is one, whereas if I chose the fair die, then the probability is 1/6. Do I just average these probabilities and say that the probability of rolling a 3 is 7/12?

Answer (score 1):

Find $P\left(\text{result is }3\right)$, $P\left(\text{result is }3\mid\text{fair die is rolled}\right)$
and $P\left(\text{fair die is rolled}\right)$.

This enables you to find:
$$P\left(\text{fair die is rolled}\mid\text{result is }3\right)$$ on base of equality:$$P\left(\text{fair die is rolled}\mid\text{result is }3\right)P\left(\text{result is }3\right)=$$$$P\left(\text{result is }3\mid\text{fair die is rolled}\right)P\left(\text{fair die is rolled}\right)$$

Comment: But how can I find P(result is 3) if the probability of the result being 3 is dependent on which die was rolled?

Comment: By means of $P(\text{result is }3)=P(\text{result is }3\mid\text{fair die is rolled})P(\text{fair die is rolled})+P(\text{result is }3\mid\text{unfair die is rolled})P(\text{unfair die is rolled})$

Comment: @K.King Law of total probability. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The probability of choosing either die is 0.5, and the probability of seeing a three is approximately 0.583 (easy exercise).

Similarly the probability of picking the fair die **and** seeing a three is approximately 0.083, whereas the probability of picking the biased die **and** seeing a three is simply 0.5.

Use [Bayes’ rule](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem) to calculate the probability of choosing either die, given that a three was observed.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your *prior* (belief before the event) is that you picked the normal die with probability $p$. Under this prior, there is a $p/6$ chance of picking the normal die and rolling a $3$ but a $1-p$ chance of picking the same-sided die and rolling a $3$. Therefore the *posterior* (belief after the event) is that you picked the normal die with probability
$$\frac{p/6}{p/6+1-p}=\frac p{6-5p}$$
Since $6-5p\ge1$, you are more confident that you picked the same-sided die after observing a $3$. In the case of $p=\frac12$ this works out to a revised probability of $\frac67$ that you picked the same-sided die.